# ElasticSearch for data scientists

Tags: beginner, information-retrieval, reference-request, career, self-study

This is to seek career advice for a data scientist. What pertains within the role of data scientist and what does not regarding ElasticSearch.

Does backend development for ElasticSearch using languages/frameworks such as Node.js, Django etc fall under the role of data scientist, or does it come under software engineering/hard code backend development? I believe there are many data scientists in this forum who work on ElasticSearch, so I thought of checking if anyone has also expanded their role as a backend developer for ElasticSearch.